# How can I install libjpeg?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I need `libjpeg` on [Dlib C++](http://dlib.net/). Can anyone help me install the `libjpeg` package?

Answer (score 21):

You can install `libjpeg` and its headers with:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```